# Adding individual image in Dropdown item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a separate image into Dropdown options. Changing image field of option in inspector doesn't give the desired result. I can't solve the problem in code:

```
public class FillDroPDown : MonoBehavior {
  public Dropdown dd;

  void Start () {
     dd.options.Clear();
     dd.AddOptions(new List<Dropdown.OptionData> {
     new Dropdown.OptionData {text="1", 
     image=Resources.Load("LeftToRight.png", typeof(Sprite)) 
     as Sprite}
     });
  }

void Update () {

  }
}
```

The text is displayed, but there is no image. I have created a Resources folder and copied the image there. How this problem can be solved? My Unity version is 5.3.4f1.

Comment: goodness!  I had ***no idea*** Unity had added a "dropdown" system!

Comment: to begin with, why bother loading it from resources?  just go `public Sprite happySprite;` and **drag it to the Inspector**.  then use that in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added a public Sprite field on class, bind it with a image. Then I initialize image field of option by this Sprite field. Again text is displayed but image not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved in the following way: in path to the resource object is not necessary to add the file extension. Also in the `Dropdown` object you need to install `Item Image` property to "`Item Background`" of this `Dropdown`. To set image into the caption you can add `Image` object to `Dropdown` and set `Caption Image` property to this added image.